# EDT is not working properly with recursive method while updating lable

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, event-dispatch-thread, settext

//search files and directories

```
public  void getFile1(String directoryName) throws Exception {

    File directory = new File(directoryName);
    String str = directory.getName();
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
    if (fList != null) {
        for (File file : fList) {
            {                        

            if (file.isFile()) 
            {
                st = (file.toString());                 

               System.out.println(st);    
                jLable1.setText(st);//jLable1 is not updating.


                String fileName = file.getName();
                String strvirusCount=Integer.toString(virusCount); 
               }
            else if (file.isDirectory())

                    {
                      getFile1(file.getAbsolutePath());

                    }               

             globalCount++;       


    }

}
```

//while retrieving all files and folder unable to update label 
when process start to  with retrieving path Swing form get unresponsive.

Comment: I think you'll find that the EDT is working perfectly. Your code isn't working properly...

Answer (score 3):

You're executing a task that takes a long time (iterating through every file, recursively), from the event dispatch thread. So, while this method is executing, the EDT can't do anything else. So it can't do what it's supposed to do: repaint the components and react to user events.

This task should be done in a separate thread, using for example a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), which will notify its progress regularly in order to update the label text. The javadoc has examples.