# Java: setText before performing a time-consuming task

Tags: java

I am trying to set the text of a `JTextArea` before doing a really slow task, I tried doing it following this code, but for some reason it first finish the method `convert` and then it changes the text of my `textArea`.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
...
    textArea.setText("Converting your file...\n");

    //Time-consuming task
    File newFile = convert(oldFile);
...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried manually calling `textArea.update()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [EDT is not working properly with recursive method while updating lable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22423696/edt-is-not-working-properly-with-recursive-method-while-updating-lable) and of dozens of other similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest to move your time consuming task to another thread. This way you could update your UI thread without any delay. Check this [SwingWorker example post](http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/) which explains why you should use another thread and how to do it, in detail.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score -1):

You can just separate your tasks into 2 different methods. If somehow the `textArea.setText()` is not executing first then you can add an `actionListener` to set your text in the `JTextArea` and another `actionListener` to execute your slow task method. Like for instance

```
    this.jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                File newFile = convert(oldFile);
            }
    });
    this.jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                jTextArea1.setText("Converting your file...\n");
            }
    });
```

The `ActionListener` added latest will be executed first. So add your status method after the slow task method.